# Specialize variadic template to skip non-reference parameters

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, variadic-templates

I am writing a wrapper for some client-server function calls, and I need a way to set some output parameter before or after the actual call. Sample code follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void tryp(int a, int b, int &c, std::vector<char> ghost) { c = 7; }

void AssignRefs() {
    std::cout << "P2" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void IsolateRef(T &&t) {
    t = 99;
}

template<typename T, typename ... A>
void AssignRefs(T &&t, A && ... a) {
    IsolateRef(t);
    std::cout << "P1" << std::endl;
    AssignRefs(a ...);
}

template<typename ... A>
std::function<void(A ...)> wrap(void (*fn)(A ...)) {
  return [](A ... a) { AssignRefs(a ...); };
}

int main() {
    int z = 6;
    int y = 4;
    int a = 9;
    int b = 77;
    tryp(1,4,y,std::vector<char>{'H'});
    wrap(tryp)(1,2,z,std::vector<char>{'Z'});
    std::cout << "Results here: " << y << " :: " << z << " :: " << a << " :: " << b << std::endl;
}
```

This of course does not compile. See [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJNa4NAED3HXzFNIdGyDSSEhqgVvKW3UgKFlh4268YI6yq6ppiQ3273w7Ya273M15s3j5kleX5PGOZx09wmnLAqouAnWSkKitPA@s3tK05EknHMulmJS3jczRwpEVkRWNYxSyIQRZ3bCReAESizM2ZCEJQicl2D9skBFwHEBznXgTMQeISVB5eWJCzLJOYvdF/asmqNdCfJKgG@D@PnxVhZnaQ8Yp4l@wRNc4aF1CPqnHKcUtgGhu2pzFRF0tlbmEyEphRy4nrda@10IvjxZ7MZhMFAl2ZCEEqjIVizdkYJxxsIn18LH3UYseJx/lHUqtCt34fxlSY71G0BfBY4t7VK@27PnTavVAEUVFQFh/cPk9ViYTgaLnq6uleKE252r6KTXNaDZ/xa@svWx2qJrb9TJ1x5cpp5@iPM0RLVaHD483Qzvaj9aNEK6UjoAp3@gr4ZaH@VG8pYhuA1K1h0A3qttS6A65rw1A9xP9xd/6Cm@QI) link for more information. It would work if I deleted the line `"t = 99"`.

What I really need is a template specialization for `AssignRefs` or `IsolateRef` to skip over non-reference parameters.

The issue now is that if I omit the `'&&'` before the type in the function definition, all parameters would lose their reference qualifier, and the call to `IsolateRef` would not do anything. But with the `'&&'` every parameter is passed by reference to the function `IsolateRef`.

I want two separate functions, one to operate on non-const reference types and the other to skip over the rest of the parameters.

Is there any simple way to implement it in the above code?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: *"This of course does not compile."* - you should provide compilation commands and build log in the question itself. Links tend to die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you might use `std::forward` and replace `IsolateRef(T &&t)` by 2 overloads, one for non-const reference, and one for const reference (No-op)

```
template <typename T> void IsolateRef(T &t) { t = 99; }
template <typename T> void IsolateRef(const T &) { /*Empty*/ }

template<typename T, typename ... A>
void AssignRefs(T &&t, A && ... a) {
    IsolateRef(std::forward<T>(t));
    std::cout << "P1" << std::endl;
    AssignRefs(std::forward<A>(a) ...);
}

template<typename ... A>
std::function<void(A ...)> wrap(void (*fn)(A ...)) {
  return [](A ... a) { AssignRefs(std::forward<A>(a) ...); };
}
```

[Demo](https://tio.run/##lVJLS8NAED6bXzFWqElZKy1FsYmBHIR6EykIioftZlsDyW7YTJW09LfXfYSatB50L/PY@Wa@ebCyvGI5Fav9/iITLF@nHKJMVqg4LWLvx7dcC4aZFDRve3VcJlZtzydnKFXseZ8ySwFVXfqZQKAEjFg40WcEKkynUxcdsQ@qYlh96LoBbIHBPdyGsGuSJFWVrcQzX1a@/vXOLJLJNUIUQe9p3DPSOrlI89DTOORFmVPUfLAuuaAFh3nssj1W0vzodP4c@mgzoi54d/cPJJOiQtB4Q/d68FCUWA@uDeNDghaewEEfDoeQxCd96Ux9JJBoYUOopdUqaNtbSvVFVRrNYx@DIDyZxOh4EmetEp0MSezrErpS0Gk6OubpQM3qI8PaTywshi9FS9/24Q@WImj8hjeA4rhWAt7ende2A3/gAjtLx5xIQTPh1m2sjV7QTej0WuuTRqdmcY2@MFdzG@ry7tnbG5EJqcnJrW0vZ5c7M0HbhYkMdOiYbH4LfXWh3WHPeJ5LAi9S5ek52MHX9gOmU2duuibtmovjo93vvwE)

Comment: Yes, this is definitely easier that every other solution. It's just the tiny little piece that I was missing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution could be to *check* if `t` can be assigned 99:

```
#include <type_traits>
// [...]

if constexpr (std::is_assignable_v<T&&, int>) {
    IsolateRef(t);
}
```

You can then improve `IsolateRef` to be a no-op for non-assignable types so it can be called without knowledge of its internals:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
concept IntAssignable = std::is_assignable_v<T, int>;

template <typename T>
requires (IntAssignable<T&&>)
void IsolateRef(T &&t) {
    t = 99;
}

template <typename T>
requires (!IntAssignable<T&&>)
void IsolateRef(T &&)
{}

// ...
int n;
std::vector<int> v;
IsolateRef(n); // assigns
IsolateRef(v); // no-op
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dTW7Ydjh9)

Comment: This is something I already tried by means of `std::enable_if`, but it doesn't actually separate the ref from the non-ref. I need to assign a value to certain parameters but only if they are defined as reference to *any* type, not just integers.

Comment: I understand from your question that the core issue is not the referenceness of your parameters, but their capacity to be assigned `99`. Reference or not, assigning `99` to a vector fails. This answer take care of this issue. If this is not a solution to your problem, please clarify the question. This answer fixes the code given in the OP.

Comment: I updated also the question title to reflect that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you willing to pass a vector to `wrap(f)` as reference?  `auto v = std::vector<char>{'V'}; wrap(tryp)(v);`?

Comment: Yes, that could happen, then a specialization of another template function would handle that case and fill the vector.

Comment: Ok that was the information I missed.

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution that just popped up in my head.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void IsolateRef(T &&t) {
    t = 99;
}

template<typename... Ts>
std::function<void(Ts...)> wrap(void (*fn)(Ts...)){
    return [](Ts... args){
        ([]<typename V>(V&& v){
            if constexpr(std::is_reference_v<Ts>){
                IsolateRef(std::forward<V>(v));
            }
        }(args), ...);
    };
}

void tryp(int a, int b, int &c, std::vector<char> ghost) { c = 7; }

int main() {
    int z = 6;
    int y = 4;
    int a = 9;
    int b = 77;
        tryp(1,4,y,std::vector<char>{'H'});
    wrap(tryp)(1,2,z,std::vector<char>{'Z'});
    std::cout << "Hello, World! " << y << " :: " << z << " :: " << a << " :: " << b << std::endl;
}
```

I originally wrote a function trait to extract the parameter types of the original function, including whether they are references or not. However, it turns out it is not really needed.

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/n9EdvGxbn

For the sake of completeness, this is the function trait I originally wrote:

```
template<typename F, int N> struct DumbFunctionTrait{};

template<typename R, typename... Ts, int N>
struct DumbFunctionTrait<R(Ts...), N>{
    using type = std::tuple_element_t<N, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
};
```

This solution is more general and does not include anything specific to `int` or `99`. However, I am not sure this is what OP needs, or whether it is an XY problem. This is the best I can get to answer the question as stated.